# Problems with HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis .allAsleepValues

Tags: swift, swiftui, healthkit

I'm trying to retrieve sleep states using HealthKit and I keep getting the error

Type 'Set < HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis > ' has no member 'allAsleepValues'

on this line

'''

import Foundation

import HealthKit

let allAsleepPredicate = HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.predicateForSamples(equalTo: .allAsleepValues)

'''

I've updated my Xcode the most recent version 14.01 and my phone is on iOS 16.
Really not trying to do anything fancy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let allAsleepPredicate = HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.predicateForSamples(equalTo: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.allAsleepValues)
```

Comment: This looks interesting, it will retrieve all states of sleep in a structure? I cant test now so thats why I ask, also I would like to propose something to you JPC, where could I contact you?